# Ruby Redis - Thread Performance

Tags: ruby, multithreading, redis

I'm using Ruby 1.8.7 and the redis-rb gem. I tried various approaches to write 1 million records to a Redis List.

I noticed that the performance is suffering when I'm using Threads. What is the reason for that, and how can I prevent that? I will use Redis in a threaded environment for production, so I'm concerned.

Here are my results:

```
1_000_000.times do
  $r.rpush "test_list", rand(1_000_000)
end
# Took: 74.2986769676208 sec.

threads = []
1_000.times do
  threads << Thread.new {
    1_000.times {
      $r.rpush "test_list", rand(1_000_000)
    }
  }
end
threads.each { |k| k.join }
# Took: 391.705540895462 sec.

mutex = Mutex.new
threads = []
1_000.times do
  threads << Thread.new {
    1_000.times {
      mutex.synchronize {
        $r.rpush "test_list", rand(1_000_000)
      }
    }
  }
end
threads.each { |k| k.join }
# Took: 308.474660873413 sec.

mutex = Mutex.new
threads = []
10.times do
  threads << Thread.new {
    100_000.times {
      mutex.synchronize {
        $r.rpush "test_list", rand(1_000_000)
      }
    }
  }
end
threads.each { |k| k.join }
# Took: 109.103996992111 sec.

forks = []
8.times do
  forks << fork {
    125_000.times {
      $r.rpush "test_list", rand(1_000_000)
    }
  }
end
forks.each { |k| Process.wait(k) }
# Took: 23.7934968471527 sec.
```

Comment: Threads in ruby 1.8.7 do not run concurrently. You basically get the same single-threaded performance but lose resources on overhead.

Comment: good suggestion, what exactly causes the overhead? is it failed read/writes that are getting re-tried often? do you see a way to reduce the overhead?

Comment: Threading overhead. Creating, managing and destroying threads.

Comment: It can't be just the thread overhead. When running 1000 empty Threads, each with a 1000.times loop (as in the example) but without the redis command, it takes 0.166961908340454 sec. VS 391.705 sec.

Comment: even 1,000,000 threads finish in 9.09597611427307 sec.

Comment: You would better served by pipelining rather than using threads. On server side, everything is serialized anyway. At least, if you want to use threads, be sure to use one Redis connection per thread ...

Comment: Could you elaborate regarding pipelining?
Unfortunately I'm using Redis in a threaded project, so I can't prevent that. One Redis connection per thread sounds like a lot.
Can anybody explain what exactly is causing this "overhead" when using threads with Redis? Maybe there is a way to optimize that, this would be the perfect solution for me.

Comment: http://www.igvita.com/2008/11/13/concurrency-is-a-myth-in-ruby/

Comment: Pipelining: see http://redis.io/topics/pipelining - Threading overhead: it is not specific to Redis connections. Ruby MRI 1.8 implements only green threads, with a global interpreter lock. If you use threads, keep a low number of them, a create one Redis connection per thread.

Comment: I would try this threaded code on rubinius out of curiosity: http://rubini.us It does not have the GIL.

Answer (score 0):

BUMP!

This is a really good example, as it shows lots of scenarios. Should we assume that the correct number of entries end up in "test_list" on redis, because I wonder about the first example... ? (A count would be useful to see after the threads are joined)

So, my interpretation:

> **1 Thread, 1 million writes each**

*Execution Time: 74 seconds*

Single Connection to redis with serialized writes

> **1000 Threads, 100 writes each, no ruby mutex**

*Execution Time: 380 seconds*

I think we have to assume Redis is using it's own mutex for writes so the "overhead" here will be a result of Redis's own mutex. This may be due to the fact that each thread is sharing the same client object to write - did you try creating 1000 redis clients? :)

> **1000 Threads, 1000 writes each, ruby mutex**

*Execution Time: 308 seconds*

It looks like the writes ("set") to Redis are coming in a more orderly fashion due to the mutex being inside the ruby threads. Here the overhead is the 999 threads that have to wait for the 1 thread to write to Redis...

> **10 Threads, 100,000 writes each, local mutex**

*Execution Time: 108 seconds*

Less threads waiting around for the mutex each time, so the cycle of writes is quicker.

> **8 forks, 125,000 writes each**

*Execution Time: 23 seconds*

There is still a little overhead here, but otherwise this is 8 different Redis connections writing 125,000 keys each. Redis laps it up... the "overhead" is in the forking of the ruby process I think (otherwise you would expect something more like 10 seconds)

Thanks for putting up the test - it's really instructional, and I am going to show it to our developers as a training exercise!